# Filegeodatabase fanout and Python problem

Tags: python, postgis, fme-form, file-geodatabase

I have fme wb which does fanout with gdb. It means that in the end as output sets of data I get few new created gdb. But If I start this fme wb within python script It does not do fanout. Just write data in one gdb. i do not understand where could be a problem?

Comment: Could you add the python that starts the workbench.

Comment: But code is for long. Just this part is: print os.system(), in brackets comes string with path of fme.exe and path of workbench.

Comment: Interesting is that if the fanout gdb are created with just fme wb first, and then I start python which start fme wb and overwrite them, then everything is working regulary. And this is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on my system and for me it worked and did the fanout whether I started from python or not.  Maybe you could check your fanout parameters against mine.[image: ScreenShot]

Here is a sample [workspace](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2377887/filegdb.fmw).  And here is the code I used in python:
import os
print os.system("c:/apps/FME2012/fme.exe C:/Stack/none2filegdb.fmw")